# Email to Document Library - Place attachments in sub folders

Tags: 2007, folder, incoming-email

I am having issues with scheduling Crystal Reports to go into specified folders so I am taking a different route and using emails & attachments.

As the title suggests, I'd like to automate where these attachments go within a Document Library based on the subject (or file name). I know you can specify either the document Library root or the folder pertaining to the Email Subject, but I was wondering if you can extend beyond this, such as:

**Email Subject:** 'Animals - Felines - Cats'

**Location placed:** 'Document Library root/Animals/Felines/Cats'

Edit: Assuming there is no solution for this?

Comment: Should I still reply this question? I stumpled on it and could deliver the answer, though I'm not sure if I should reopen this 3 year old question.

Comment: Hey mate, this is racking my brain to way back, let me get into work tomorrow and touch base with a few people to see if we solved it. @andreas